# Error:(51, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable mTracker Google Analytics

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, analytics

Hi I am try put Google Analytics in my app and I see the documentation but don't work for me, I have this error Error:(51, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable mTracker:

AnalyticsApplication.java

```
public class AnalyticsApplication extends Application {
private Tracker mTracker;

/**
 * Gets the default {@link Tracker} for this {@link Application}.
 * @return tracker
 */
synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
    if (mTracker == null) {
        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        // To enable debug logging use: adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
        mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
    }
    return mTracker;
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


<application
    .....
</application>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int n;
String adc;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Obtain the shared Tracker instance.
    MYPACKAGE.AnalyticsApplication application = (MYPACKAGE.AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
    mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
```

...

Error:
Error:(51, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable mTracker

FIXED:
The problem was that I need to put this in the MainActivity:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
int n;
String adc;
**private Tracker mTracker;**
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Obtain the shared Tracker instance.
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to put "private Tracker mTracker;" in the main activity

Answer (score 0):

Your MainActivity class is using the field mTracker, which is defined in the Application.

Suggest you change the code like so:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Obtain the shared Tracker instance.
    MYPACKAGE.AnalyticsApplication application = (MYPACKAGE.AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
    Tracker tracker = application.getDefaultTracker(); // Changed.
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your manifest :

```
<application
name = "yourpackagename.applicationclassname"
    .....
</application>
```

try this, this will work